# No value specified for parameter 3, когда в действительности ВСЕ параметры(их 5) установлены

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

```
@Override
public int changeBanState(boolean isActive, int id, Date fromDate, Date toDate) throws DataAccessException {
    String query = MessageFormat.format(
            "UPDATE {0} SET {1} = ?, {2} = ? WHERE {3} = ? AND {4} = ? AND {5} = ?",
            usersBannedTableName,
            usersBannedTableRemovedFieldName,
            usersBannedTableRemovedDateFieldName,
            usersBannedTableUserIDFieldName,
            usersBannedTableFromDateFieldName,
            usersBannedTableToDateFieldName);

    System.out.println(query);
    System.out.println(isActive ? 1/*"true"*/ : 0/*"false"*/);
    System.out.println(isActive ? "curdate()" : "null");
    System.out.println(id);
    System.out.println(dbDateFormater.format(fromDate));
    System.out.println(dbDateFormater.format(toDate));
    return jdbcTemplate.update(
            query,
            new Object[] {
                    (isActive ? 1/*"true"*/ : 0/*"false"*/), 
                    (isActive ? "curdate()" : "null"),
                    id,
                    dbDateFormater.format(fromDate),
                    dbDateFormater.format(toDate)},
            Integer.class);
}
```

Вывод:

> UPDATE users_banned SET removed = ?, removed_date = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND _from = ? AND _to = ?
>   1
>   curdate()
>   2
>   2020-06-06
>   2020-06-06

Как видно, **ВСЕ 5** вопросиков должны замениться на 5 заданных значений. В интернете обычно человек просто забывает установить все значения вопросиков, а у меня все это есть(хоть и косвенно - через массив объектов).

Полная ошибка:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with
>   path [/MVC] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE users_banned SET
>   removed = ?, removed_date = ? WHERE user_id = ? AND _from = ? AND _to
>   = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: No value
>   specified for parameter 3     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1115)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
>     at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:867)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:917)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:927)
>     at
>   ru.miron.DAOsImpls.MySQLUserDAO.changeBanState(MySQLUserDAO.java:187)
>     at
>   ru.miron.Controllers.AdminToolsController.changeUserBanState(AdminToolsController.java:212)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Comment: Может даты не в том формате?

Comment: у вас id является int, орм такое не любит, сделайте айдишник Integer

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець в том, я привел вывод.

Comment: @Дмитрий Пробовал. И String тоже

Comment: Больше скажу - если тупо вручную подставить и запустить без параметров на замену(перегруз ф-ции), то выкинет `Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).`.

Comment: Вообще у меня много запросов в классе. Просто все они либо `INSERT`, либо `SELECT`. Это наверняка связано с тем, что запрос типа `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, по привычке(например, `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, new Object[] {login}, Integer.class)` - там у меня запрос `COUNT(*)` получает, я и пишу, что нужно сразу преобразовать в `Integer`) написал как последний параметр `Integer.class`. А оно его воспринимает, как аргумент. Записался))